# Can I execute free() or close() in a signal handler?

Tags: c, signals

I have a code that looks like this:

```
//global variables

void signal_handler() {
    //deallocation of global variables
    free(foo);
    close(foo_2);
    exit(0);
}

int main () {
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);

    //irrelevant code
}
```

As you can see, I changed the `CTRL+C` interruption to execute the `signal_handler` function once instead of killing the process right away. I read somewhere that some functions like might be `free` are not async-safe and would NOT execute in the `signal_handler` but I'm not sure about that.

Can I execute functions like `free`, `close`, `exit` or even `pthread_join` in a signal handler?

Comment: No. asdfasdfasfsadfas

Comment: What kind of software are you coding? Some web thing, some scientific code (e.g. [CAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-aided_design) software) or some C code driving a nuclear missile? What happens to you when your software crashes?

Comment: This is basically the same question as [How to avoid using `printf()` in a signal handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16891019/15168). There's a list of functions that can be called in a signal handler (`close()` is one, but `fclose()` is not; neither `free()` nor `exit()` is, but you can call `_exit()` or `_Exit()` safely instead; `pthread_join()` is not callable from a signal handler).

Answer (score 1):

No. Only functions listed in [man 7 signal-safety](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) are safe to call inside a signal handler.

`close` is listed and should be safe. `free` is not. For reasons why you would have to look at its source code (it contains locks). `exit` is not safe because it can call arbitrary cleanup handlers. You have `_exit` which exits abruptly without the cleanup.

Comment: Note: `pthread_join` in its current glibc implementation looks safeish to me, but the standard does not guarantee that other implementations or future versions of it would be as well. The man page does mention some other `pthread_*` functions so the absence of `pthread_join` should be interpreted as it being unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

You techincally can compile a program that calls such functions in a signal handler, nothing stops you from doing that. However it will result in undefined behavior if the function you are trying to execute is not async-signal-safe. It's not like unsafe function would just "NOT execute" as you say, they very well could, but that'd still be undefined behavior.

A list of async-signal-safe functions is documented in [`man 7 signal-safety`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html). The `close()` function is safe, while `free()` and `phtread_join()` are not. The `exit()` function is also *not* safe to call from a signal handler, if you wish to exit from such context you will have to do so using [`_exit()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/exit) instead.

The only way to safely call a function that is not async-signal-safe when receiving a signal is to "remember" that you have to call it (for example setting a global variable) and then do so *after* returning from the signal handler.

Comment: If you something that causes UB, you get UB even before you reach that point. So technically you can't according to the C standard, because a program that causes UB could do nothing at all.

Comment: free could probably deadlock, if the thread was interrupted while inside memory allocation routines.

Comment: @SvenNilsson oh yeah it surely could, that's one of the infinite amount of possibilities when invoking undefined behavior :')

Comment: @MarcoBonelli In reality yes. But not according to the C standard. If your program will reach UB sometimes in the future, with the information the program already has, nothing is guaranteed even before hitting that point. Your compiler may know that `free()` can't be called in a signal handler and optimize away the `signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);` call.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 I'll give you that "compiler optimizations are assuming no undefined behavior" etc, etc. Though I don't think that's a thing at all, it would have to be documented as per C99 $3.4.3.2. In any case, yeah, I'll just reword to make it clear in both contexts.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no:

> **7.1.4 Use of library functions**
> ...
> 4     The functions in the standard library are not guaranteed to be reentrant and may modify
> objects with static or thread storage duration.<sup>188)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>188) Thus, a signal handler cannot, in general, call standard library functions</sup>

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

Real-world example of the consequences - I worked on a system that communicated with an Access database.  There was a signal handler that tried to write an error message to the console with `fprintf`, but somehow during the signal handling process `stderr` got mapped to the .mdb file that stored the database, overwriting the header and ruining the database beyond repair.

There's honestly not a whole lot you *can* do in a signal handler other than set a flag to be checked elsewhere.

Comment: Note that Standard C only permits the operations that every implementation can support — a very minimal set of operations.  POSIX makes much more stringent demands on the system and there is an extensive collection of functions that can be used safely from signal handlers — as noted in my answer to the duplicate question.

Comment: C11 [§7.14.1.1 The `signal` function ¶5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.14.1.1p5) specifies the rules: _If the signal occurs other than as the result of calling the `abort` or `raise` function, the behavior is undefined if the signal handler refers to any object with static or thread storage duration that is not a lock-free atomic object other than by assigning a value to an object declared as `volatile sig_atomic_t`, or the signal handler calls any function in the standard library other than the `abort` function, the `_Exit` function, the `quick_exit` function, … _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ … _or the `signal` function with the first argument equal to the signal number corresponding to the signal that caused the invocation of the handler. Furthermore, if such a call to the `signal` function results in a SIG_ERR return, the value of errno is indeterminate._ It also references footnote 252 which says: _If any signal is generated by an asynchronous signal handler, the behavior is undefined._  POSIX provides more reasonable semantics, and other platforms likewise extend what is defined behaviour over and above what the C standard permits (which is very minimal).

Answer (score 0):

> Can I execute free() or close() in a signal handler?

### You definitely should not. See [signal(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [signal-safety(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)

**In practice, it might work like you want perhaps more than half of the time.** IIRC, the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler is doing like you want to do, and it usually works.

A better approach is to use some [write(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) to a [pipe(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) (from inside your signal handler) and from time to time check that pipe (in your main program) with [poll(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) or related things.

Or you could set some `volatile sigatomic_t flag;` (perhaps it should be also [`_Atomic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic)) in your signal handler, and check that flag elsewhere (in the main program, outside of signal handlers).

[Qt is explaining that better](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/unix-signals.html) than I could do in a few minutes.

On Linux, see also [signalfd(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) and [eventfd(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html).